# Extra whitespace around content_for value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whitespace, render, content-for

I need to give my body tag a page-specific id to better target css selectors.

To this end I have set up the following in my application.erb layout:

```
<body id="<%= content_for :page_id %>">
```

Inside a page's view I can then do this:

```
<% content_for :page_id do %>
  <%='some-page-id'%>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I am getting extra whitespace returned around the returned value resulting in the rendered body tag looking like this:

```
<body id="    some-page-id " >
```

This prevents the id from working. I have a workaround in place where I do this:

```
<% body_id = content_for :page_id %>
<body id="<%= body_id.strip %>">
```

But is there a way to fix this so that content_for returns its value without extra whitespace? What is causing this extra whitespace to be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is causing this extra whitespace to be returned?

The space

```
<% content_for :page_id do %>
  <%='some-page-id'%>
<% end %>
```

You could try this:

```
<%- content_for :page_id do -%>
  <%='some-page-id'%>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: My god I feel like a fool. I was looking for space inside <%='some-page-id'%> when obviously it was the space between <% content_for :page_id do %> and <% end %>. I would delete this from shame but I think you deserve a green tick and I deserve the shame.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use extra ERB delimiters to set the content

```
<% content_for(:page_id) { "thepageid" } %>
```

You can go further and define a helper method

```
# in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def page_id(page_id)
  content_for(:page) { page_id }
end

# in your template
<% page_id("thepageid") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always make it a one-liner with:

```
<body id="<%= content_for(:page_id).strip %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

@OscarDelBen is correct:

This is what works:

```
<% content_for :page_id do %><%='some-page-id'%><% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour of Rails, I recommend you add "id=" inside content_for

```
<body "<%= content_for :page_id %>">

<% content_for :page_id do %>
  <%='id="some-page-id"' %>
<% end %>
```